# Selecting Alternate rows as separate column

Tags: sql-server-2005, rows

I have a table like this:

```
  Date          Day
-------------------------
  2010-01-02    Saturday
  2010-01-03    Sunday
  2010-01-09    Saturday
  2010-01-10    Sunday
  ........      ......
  ........      ........
```

I want to show it as follows:

```
    FromDate    FromDay    ToDate       ToDay
---------------------------------------------------------
  2010-01-02    Saturday   2010-01-03    Sunday
  2010-01-09    Saturday   2010-01-10    Sunday 
  ........      ........   ...........   ......
  ........      ........   ...........   ......
```

I've just copied the query from http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/12/29/sql-server-get-date-of-all-weekdays-or-weekends-of-the-year/

```
 But I don't know how to split as required.
```

Comment: How big the table is? Couple of hundreds/ thousands?  million? Or more?

Comment: Hundreds.. Totally 104 rows available in it.

Comment: Ok, use Row_Number() over (order by feomdate) to assign sequential number to each row. Get CTE with this result. Use this CTE and get only ODD numbered rows in second CTE. As a final select use second CTE and do pivot on row number and get ToDate as column. In the same result use similar row_number function to assign sequential numbers to each of thi row. name thus column row number as rowid1. Join with cte2 on rowed and rowid1